# Unpack 2 columns for list in Dataframe to get its corresponding values to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-preprocessing

I have a sample of the dataframe as given below.

```
data = {'Participant':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Total Entry':[2, 3, 1, 3],
    'Time':[['2021-07-12', '2021-07-16'],['2021-07-21','2021-07-22','2021-07-24'],['2021-06-20'],['2021-07-26','2021-07-29','2021-08-01']],
    'Values':[['Negative','Negative'],['Positive','Positive','Negative'],['Negative'],['Negative','Positive','Negative']]}

df_test= pd.DataFrame(data)
df_test
```

[image]

I want to unpack corresponding values of 2 columns and append it to the corresponding rows. The final obtained result is shown below.

[image]

I tried using pop, unstack and Series functions, but it is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
df_test.explode(['Time', 'Values'])
```

Comment: I am getting an Value Error as given: 
"ValueError: column must be a scalar"

Comment: Try separately first `df_test = df_test.explode('Time')` and then
`df_test = df_test.explode('Values')`

Comment: It does not work as well because it gives all combination of 'Time' and 'Values' which results in a bigger dataframe of 23 rows
. I require only corresponding values with 9 rows.

Comment: Figured. `df_test.set_index(['Participant','Total Entry']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()`   works.